# Read Vector from Text File

Tags: python, numpy

I have a text file with a bunch of number that contains newlines every 32 entries. I want to read this file a a column vector using Numpy. How can I use `numpy.loadtxt` and ignore the newlines such that the generated array is of size 1024x1 and not 32x32?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `loadtxt` and `reshape` (or `ravel`) the resulting array.